# node-postgres: multi-query is atomic?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise, node-postgres

When using `pg-promise` (based on `node-postgres`), a [`multi`](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi)-query seems to be atomic.

For example, the following `PostgreSQL` query does not insert any rows at all even though only the second `INSERT` fails due to a duplicate id. No transactions are used.

```
insert into mytable (id) values (1); insert into mytable (id) values (1)
```

This behavior seems counter-intuitive and differs from that of `psql`. Is this a bug?

Comment: `pg-promise` does not provide any automatic transaction when executing method `multi`, which means the question should be directed at its [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) driver. Other than that, I wouldn't expect the multi-query operation to be atomic, but I also never tested such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tests indicate that yes, surprisingly, it is atomic, i.e. if one query fails, they all fail, same as inside a transaction.

I will investigate why that is, and post an update, if I find anything. See [the open issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1717).

**UPDATE**

The investigation has confirmed that it is indeed how PostgreSQL works when multiple queries are sent in a single string.

Documentation for methods [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi) and [multiResult](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multiResult) has been amended accordingly:

> The operation is atomic, i.e. all queries are executed in a single transaction, unless there are explicit `BEGIN/COMMIT` commands included in the query string to divide it into multiple transactions.

Comment: Relevant discussion: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/cbqqotcde1c6s8c58nk26ui4et27agdqrq%404ax.com Not conclusive, but seems like it may be the standard behavior of postgres.

Comment: @Code I have finalized my answer. Please accept, if it is good enough ;)